# Converting string to Ruby datetime

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I have the following string as a date

```
Thu 17 Jan
```

I want to convert this to a Ruby date time object (to save in the database). I have tried [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic), but without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for chronic. Simple Date will do.

```
require 'date'

s = 'Thu 17 Jan'

Date.parse(s) # => #<Date: 2013-01-17 ((2456310j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: `require 'date'` is not necessary in Rails.

Comment: Ah, indeed, he uses rails. Anyway, it won't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use:

```
 s = 'Thu 17 Jan'

 date = DateTime.parse(s)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer this works. (Sorry I had select the Sergio's answer as correct as is the first one to post)